# How do I delete columns from Excel using OpenXML

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have the following method to delete a column from Excel using 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel'

```
public static void DeleteExcelColumn(ref Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet objSheet, List<int> deleteColumns)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range objCols = objSheet.Columns;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range objCol = null;
        foreach (int column in deleteColumns)
        {
            objCol = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)objCols[column,Type.Missing];
            objCol.EntireColumn.Delete(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlDeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftToLeft);
        }

        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objCols);
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objCol);
    }
```

How do i achieve the same by using "OpenXML"

```
public static void DeleteExcelColumnUsingOpenXML(ref DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Worksheet objSheet, List<int> deleteColumns)
{
         SheetData sheetData = objSheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
        foreach (int column in deleteColumns)
        {
            sheetData.Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Columns>() ???
            // delete column
        }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Take reference from this site

https://bytescout.com/products/developer/spreadsheetsdk/bytescoutxls_remove_columns_from_existing_excel_document.html

Comment: This is a link to a 3rd party product. The question specifically asked for a solution using open xml sdk